# How do I stream a generated file for download in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, streaming, unicorn

I would like for a user to be able to click a "download" link and have a file download while it's being generated. As in, the download begins immediately, even before the file generation is completed. The following code appears to stream when I request it from curl, but waits for the entire generation to finish before initiating the download when requested through firefox or chrome:

```
class Streamer
  def each  
    1200.times do |i|  
      yield i.to_s + "\n"
      sleep 0.1
    end
    yield "END\n"
  end  
end

class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def stream
    headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"
    headers["Content-disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"test.txt\""
    headers['X-Accel-Buffering'] = 'no'
    headers["Cache-Control"] ||= "no-cache"
    #headers["Transfer-Encoding"] = "chunked"
    headers.delete("Content-Length")
    self.response.status = 200
    self.response_body = Streamer.new
  end

end
```

Uncommenting the transfer encoding breaks streaming for curl. I'm running:

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails --config-file unicorn.config.rb
```

and unicorn.config.rb is:

```
listen 3000, tcp_nopush: false, :tcp_nodelay => true
```

Comment: Surely you'd have to wait for the file to be generated, as during that process, your server's processes will be tied up with the processing? Maybe you could give us more context on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318789/streaming-download-while-file-is-created?rq=1

Comment: Users provide some input which is used to create an audio file. The audio file is generated programmatically and the data can be immediately streamed for download, but the generating takes a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Brandon - I know you won't want to hear this, but have you thought about just letting the file generate before letting it download? If it's going to take a few seconds, surely you'd be better dealing with a rendered file, rather than one in processing?

Comment: It's a better user experience for these files to be streaming download; the only reason not to do this are technical restrictions. These files are only used for downloading: they're only created in response to a user request, and have no use afterwards (except possibly for caching).

Comment: As of Rails 4.2.*, I still would like an answer to the OP. Currently fighting with this myself.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but if it is useful of someone I will leave the approach I would follow.

Maybe you can use background jobs, and create a model which will store the sreamed file as well as some functional information like a the way to find it and its current startus.

```rb
class GeneratedFile < ActiveRecord
 # fields :status, :file_name, :streamed_content, :mime_type, :generation_message
 enum status: %i[processing ready error]
 validates :status, presence: true
end

class StaticPagesController
 def stream
   generating_file = GeneratedFile.create! do |file|
     file.processing!
   end
   # Supposing that this class exist and launches a background job
   BackgroundJob.execute_later(file: generating_file)
 end
end
```

Then inside the execution of the background job you can modify the content of the record as well as its status.

Answer (score 0):

The example code you've posted will work with Rack 2.1.x, but will no longer stream in Rack 2.2.x due to [this change in Rack::ETag](https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/0371c69a0850e1b21448df96698e2926359f17fe#diff-1bc61e69628f29acd74010b83f44d041) and how it identifies a streaming response.

When setting the response_body to a (ducktyped) Enumerable, you now need to add this Header (to prevent Rack::ETag from preprocessing the entire Enumerable to build a digest):

```
headers["Last-Modified"] = Time.current.httpdate
```